# use option output rather than option value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jquery script set up to calculate the cost of services for a user. the script works great! However, my database side calls to go another route. How can I use the actual output of the option for the calculation rather than the value

**jquery:**

```
    var $selections = $('#selections');
var $selects = $("select").change(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $selections.empty();
    $selects.each(function () {
        var $selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
        var price = parseFloat($selected.data("price")) || 0;
        total += price;
        if($selected.val() !== ''){
            $('<li />', {
                text: $selected.val() + $(this).parent().clone().children().remove().end().text()+" " + $selected.data("price")
            }).appendTo($selections)
        }
    })
    $(".summary").text('Est. Total $' + total);
})
```

**HTML with PHP:**

```
<select name="rooms" id="Areas"> 
<option value="" selected="selected">0</option>
 @foreach ($room as $rooms)
 <option data-price="{{ $rooms->pr_clean }}" value='{{ $rooms->room  }}'>{{ $rooms->room  }}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

Basically I want to be able to add something different in the value field to go into the database but still calculate how many room they are wanting to select using `{{ $rooms->room  }}`

here is a fiddle with the basic idea of how my script works. http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xf9Fp/

Comment: What do you mean by "actual output of the option"?

Comment: Did you try swapping out `val()` for `text()` ?

Comment: Yes do as @adeneo suggests and your example fiddle does.
`$selected.text()`

Comment: Looks like that worked. I tried eariler and was cauing issues adding zeros across the board so I just changed it to text() on the if statement..thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery `.val()` will give you the option's value **when** defined inside the `<option>` tag. If there is no value in the option it will get the text of the option.

```
<option value="" selected="selected">0</option>
        ^------^                     ^
         value                      text
```

So because some of your options have `value=""`, jQuery's [**.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) will get that value, which is a empty string. Without `value=""` inside the `<option>` tag `.val()` would give you `0`.

To be sure you always get **the text** of the option you can use [**.text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

**So use this:** `if($selected.text() !== ''){`